# Retrieving client credentials grant tokens when using Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, homestead, laravel-passport

I'm trying to use client credentials grant tokens for machine-to-machine authentication. I've got two separate sites (API & Web).

I've created a client credentials grant client on API.

```
php artisan passport:client --client
```

On Web, I'm trying to retrieve a token from API, using the below code. The PASSWORD_ID/PASSWORD_SECRET are stored in my .env file, I copied them directly from database so they're definitely correct.

```
$guzzle = new GuzzleHttp();
    $response = $guzzle->get('http://testsite-api.test/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'client_id' => env('PASSPORT_ID'),
            'client_secret' => env('PASSPORT_SECRET'),
        ],
    ]);
```

From this I am getting the following error:

> Client error: `POST http://testsite-api.test/oauth/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed","message":"Client authentication failed"}

Please note: I pulled this code onto my Mac (which uses valet) and it worked straight away.

I've used postman to test it, and it worked first time, using the same ID/SECRET used within Web.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I'm fairly certain it's a homestead issue, but I'm having trouble finding a resolve.

Comment: Hey, Tommy, did you check out my answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue might be with related with using `env()` function. If the config is cached with `php artisan config:cache` the `env()` function always returns `null`, you can test that by runing `php artisan config:clear` and trying to send request again, it should work just fine.

Also you should refactor your app, the `env()` should only be used in `config/` files, that way you can cache your variables and in you app simply use `config('app.PASSPORT_SECRET')`, `app` being the file name that the config is put it.

Comment: One little nitpick: the `env()` function doesn't always return `null` when the config is cached. The `env()` function will still return values for environment variables that were set when the process was started, or for values manually set by `putenv()`. However, caching the config does prevent the `.env` file from being loaded into the environment, so any values set by the `.env` file will not be available using the `env()` function. And for this reason, the `env()` function should only ever be used in the config files.